# How to have a slight gradient to edge of shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, gradient

I have a few shapes in Illustrator which I have grouped and made into a compound path. I  filled it with a gradient. (client wants a the chakra colours).

I would love to put another layer on top like a feather on the edge of the shape which softens the edge, like a stroke but not it on the inside of the shape.

Dose anyone know what i mean? or how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

- Select the frame edge shape or shapes
- Copy/Paste in front, <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> Win
- Set the fill = none
- Set the stroke = gradient black to white, choose the third stroke gradient
  option: **Apply Gradient Across Stroke**
- Increase the stroke weight
- Cut
- Select the original shape
- **Transparency panel** > **Make Opacity Mask** > Uncheck **Clip**
- Click the right square at the transparency panel to edit the mask area
- **Paste in front** <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> Win
- Click the left square at the transparency panel to go back to the editing area

[image: ANIMATION]

Comment: Thank you very much! this was very helpful. I really appreciate this!

Answer (score 1):

Depends upon the shape and the gradient you want..... regardless of everything, if you want to "soften the edge" you *have* to cut into the shape.

One way would be to merely apply `Effect > Stylize > Feather` to the group in the **Appearance Panel**.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I had already tried this. Just dose not quite give the desired look. Cuts too much into the shape. Thank you though. I appreciate that you took the time to help me :)